# How to plot year by year data from a csv file?

Tags: python

https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?ReqID=19&step=2#reqid=19&step=3&isuri=1&1921=underlying&1903=2017

I want to make the graph of the Table 2.4.5U. Personal Consumption Expenditures by Type of Product by year. But I keep getting an index error that says "list index out of range" and nothing's graphing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x=[]
y=[]

with open("usafinal.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append((row[4]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))



plt.plot(x,y, marker='o')

plt.title('Personal Consumption in America')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Expenses')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Just indented it! It's saying "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Well, maybe one of your rows does not have 5 fields in it?

Comment: have you considered using pandas?

Comment: The data's like this, so maybe it's too big?
"Table 2.4.5U. Personal Consumption Expenditures by Type of Product"
"[Millions of dollars; quarters and months are seasonally adjusted at annual rates]" 
"Bureau of Economic Analysis" 
"Line","","2018","2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019","2019","2020"
"Line","","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1"
"1","            Personal consumption expenditures",13728357,13939828,14114559,14211920,14266250,14511176,14678197,14795024,14555813
"2","Goods",4298541,4363189,4398005,4399399,4397677,4506994,4556690

Comment: I would use whatever works to make the graph come up. I just want the x to be years and the lines to be the personal consumption expenditure.

Comment: Please invest time into solving the issue by yourself. Is `len(x) == len(y)`? Can you verify that entries of x and y look legitimate (like printing `x[:5]` and y[:5]`). Solving or even attempting to solve the problem by yourself boosts your skills.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit

```
with open('download.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        try:
            if (row[4] != '') and (row[1] != ''):
                x.append(int(row[4]))
                y.append((row[1]))
        except IndexError:
            continue
```

The if statements just checks to make sure you don't have a null value, and for the error you were getting, it was trying to read the whole file and I downloaded the file to find out there are a few blank lines at the end that the function tries to read which then throws an error. If you either change your code to emit those last few lines or just remove them (which is what I did) you will have the graph you are looking for.

I hope this helps.